# how 'nunc' is used as a correlative?

Tags: syntax, meaning, conjunctive, definitions

I came across this sentence in Jerome's letter to Innocentius:
"Nunc mihi ēuānēscentibus terrīs ‘caelum undique et undique pontus’ nunc unda tenebrīs horrēscēns et caecā nocte nimbōrum spūmeī flūctūs cānēscunt".
Nunc here seems to operate like a correlative, like et...et (both... and). Would this be translated literally as 'now... now...' or is there a better way to translate it?

Comment: Have you consulted a standard dictionary? Nunc … nunc is explicitly addressed in L&S and comparable works.

Comment: I have The New College Dictionary and it's explanation is confusing to me when applied to the sentence I mentioned here.